# what is the dao equivalent to inserting and editing records in c# .net?

Tags: c#, insert, dao

I was wondering if there is an equivalent to the DAO style insert and update record code in C#. For instance, in access VBA, I could do an insert with something like this:

```
dim db As DAO.Database
dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDatabase
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tableName")

With rs
     .add
     .Fields("column1") = Textbox.Value
     .update
End With
```

Is there something similar in C# .net?? i know how to do it with parameterized queries, but for what I'm doing, it seems like the old DAO way would be quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Since VB.Net and C# .Net share the same framework... .Net it's pretty easy.  It's going to look something like:

```
DAO.Database db = CurrentDatabase(); 
DAO.Recordset rs = db.OpenRecordset("tableName");

rs.add();
rs.Fields["column1"] = Textbox.Value ;
rs.update();
```

Comment: ya but where is the DAO reference?